# Packages to fit and predict with time space dynamic models with custom spatial weights matrix

Tags: time-series, panel-data, spatial, spatio-temporal

I am modeling the diffusion of a technology product across space and time. I am hoping to model the interdependence and influence between geographies directly, and use the model to forecast future performance in specific geographies. I am a bit confused by the different terminologies (e.g. spatiotemporal model vs. spatial panel data, etc.), but the model I want to fit is

$$
Y_t = \lambda W Y_t + \phi Y_{t-1} + \theta W Y_{t-1} + X_t \beta + \epsilon_t
$$

Where:

- $W$ is the spatial weights matrix
- $\lambda$ is contemporaneous spatial dependence
- $\phi$ is temporal dependence / inertia
- $\theta$ is temporally lagged spatial dependence
- and $X_t$ and $\beta$ are the usual explanatory variables and their coefficients

The kicker is that I want to use custom weight matrices $W$ - i.e. be able to specify it directly as opposed to have it fall out of the coordinates of point-referenced data.

Many packages in `R` come very close to what I need, including `spTimer`, `spBayes`, `stem` and `splm`, but nothing quite exactly.

I was wondering if anyone knew of a package in `R` that can be used to fit these models. Would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

To run these kind of models (e.g. with `splm`) and a custom weights matrix, you just need to create a custom neighbourhood weights `listw` object. This can be done using the `glist` parameter of the `nb2listw` function from the `spdep` package.

See Charles DiMaggio's *Spatial Epidemiology Notes* for an [example](http://www.columbia.edu/~cjd11/charles_dimaggio/DIRE/resources/spatialEpiBook.pdf) of this.

Comment: that's really close, but unfortunately I haven't found the ability to estimate separate parameters for the spatial lag and the temporal lag. thank you tho!

Comment: Ah, righto, I think I understand better now. Have you looked at the CarBayesST package? There are a multitude of complex models there - from memory there is one that suits your purposes...